# How to export User & their credential from Okta

Tags: keycloak, amazon-iam, okta, idp

I am not able to find a way to get the user credentials from the okta which will be in the hash format. No API is available to make export for the credentials. To export a user I got the solution from this chrome extension ( https://github.com/gabrielsroka/gabrielsroka.github.io/tree/master/rockstar ) which is internally using the Okta API by which I am able to get the user information except credentials. I am not getting the solution to get credentials.

My main goal is to migrate Users from okta to keycloak

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that it's possible to achieve. Okta does not have any APIs to retrieve user credentials.

Comment: Then how we can perform the migration from one IDP to another.

Comment: Build a portal which will intercept user logins and user credentials to create the user in your new IdP